# read_csv : todos los datos son leidos como objetos/string

Tags: python

Tengo un fichero *csv* con el caracter ';' como separador. 
El caso es que, en dicho fichero (de unas 100.000 lineas y 30 columnas mas o menos), la mayor parte de valores son reales, a excepcion un campo "*fecha*" y algunos "*NaN*".

```
url="datos.csv"
dataset = pandas.read_csv(url, sep=';', names=names, skiprows=1, low_memory=False)
```

Al llamar a la función `read_csv`, obtengo un *dataframe* donde todo son *objetos* o *strings*, cuando lo que en realidad busco es que se detecten automáticamente los tipos de cada columna. He intentando añadir la opcion `dtype`, pero obtengo el mensaje:

> Cannot cast array from dtype('O') to dtype('float64') according to the rule 'safe'

¿Alguien tiene una idea de lo que estoy haciendo mal?

Comment: Hola Felipe, te damos la bienvenida a la comunidad. Ésta es una pregunta interesante (una pena que no sepa Python/Pandas para poder ayudar). Completa el [tour] para aprender más sobre el sitio y su funcionamiento en general (y con ello ganarás tu primera medalla).  Un saludo.

Comment: Hola Felipe, ¿sería posible que agregaras un pequeño fragmento representativo del csv para poder reproducir el problema? Unas cuantas lineas que te ocasionen el mismo problema bastan. Generalmente esto ocurre porque al menos una fila de la columna no es un valor real o el casting a un valor real no es claro, ante esto el parser opta simplemente por crear un objeto Python. Un saludo.

Comment: Hola FJSevilla. El caso es que tengo algunos 'NaN' en algunas columnas (aparecen en el csv como 'NaN', tal cual), lo cual me imagino que impide al parser de considerar a dicha columna como de tipo real. Y supongo igualmente que al intentar forzar el tipo (con el dtype), encuentra el mismo problema ya que la presencia del "NaN" (un string?) le supone un problema. Que hacer en dicho caso? Intento borrar toda referencia 'NaN' en el fichero .csv?